# How to write a dynamic compare data query?

Tags: sql-server

I want to know how to write a query for trend analysis.
Currently i'm writing like this..

```
SELECT  ri.ItemID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.DepartmentID = 'COMM' THEN ri.RequiredQty ELSE 0 END)Department1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.DepartmentID = 'BIOL' THEN ri.RequiredQty ELSE 0 END)Department2
FROM    RequisitionItem ri, Requisition r, [User] u, Department d
WHERE   ri.RequisitionID = r.RequisitionID
AND     r.UserID = u.UserID
AND     u.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
AND     r.Date BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-30'
AND     ri.ItemID = 'C001'
GROUP BY ri.ItemID
```

I need a result like i can choose at least 3 departments and 3 months for a particular item. 
I don't know how to add more than one month.
Can anyone explain me how to do it?
Thanks a lot. 
The expected result is as follows:
Sample Data :

ITEM - Clip

```
Department    Month1     Month2     Month3
COMM           20         30         34
BIOL           12         21         32
BIZ            32         24         14
```

Comment: Looks like you want dynamic pivot

Comment: Edit your question and include (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) a definition of what you mean by "trend analysis".